# On which url adress should the post method be send (the file or the directory)?

Tags: java, php, http, https

I want my php file to catch the post request to it and use the data included.
Lets say I have a file in https://example.com/myPhpfile.php

myPhpfile.php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $myData = $_POST["data"];
    $file = fopen("Data.json", "w");
    fwrite($file, $myData);
    fclose($file);  
}
?>
```

Now I want to send request from java using POST method
I need there to place URL on which I want to send the request.
Should be it
https://example.com/myPhpfile.php
or
https://example.com/
or
https://example.com

How can I know that?

Comment: You POST to a script that will receive that data you are sending, so `https://example.com/myPhpfile.php`

Comment: If you post it to a "folder" URL, it won't trigger a specific PHP script (unless a default document name is specified in the webserver config)